# Combine foreach button and label in this form

Tags: c#

I'm curious if i can combine this two code in one

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
    {
    }

foreach (Control f in this.Controls)
{
    if (f is Label)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any way that i can mix them?

Comment: `if... else if ... `?

Comment: Or, use OR (`||`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the second `foreach` and use an `else if`:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
    {
        Button button = c as Button;
        // Do something with 'button' here
    }
    else if (c is Label)
    {
        Label label = c as Label;
        // Do something with 'label' here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to do something if the control is either a `Button` *or* a `Label`, you can use an OR operator:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button || c is Label)
    {
        // Do something here
        c.Tag = "I'm a button or a label";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i use different letter for label example f?

Comment: `c` is the control we're examining. It's defined in the `foreach` loop. Inside the code block where we check if it's a label, you can create a variable to represent the label with whatever name you like. I chose `label`, but toy could use `f` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: The problem is that i have labels above each button and i need to make labels transparent with my buttons

Comment: That is not the question you asked, though... Do you have some way of identifying a label that is above a button, perhaps by it's `Name` or `Tag` property?

Comment: If you know the names of all the labels (i.e. `label1` through `label50`) then you can loop through the Controls collection and check the Name property to see if it begins with "label" and ends with a number less than or equal to 50. For example: `foreach(Control c in Controls) { int controlId; if (c.Name.StartsWith("label") && int.TryParse(c.Name.Substring(5), out controlId) && controlId <= 50) { c.BackColor = Color.Transparent; } } `